# Object A contains objects B1 and B2, B1, contains C, contains D. What is the best way to have D change something in B2?

Tags: python, oop

I'm creating an implementation of a somewhat complicated board game in Python using object oriented programming.

My problem is that a lot of these objects should be able to interact with other objects, even if they are not contained in them.

For example Game is an object, which contains PointTracker and Board. Board contains AreaOne and AreaOne contains SpaceOne.

When a Pawn is placed on AreaOne, one of the things that needs to happen is that the player placing it gets a point. Thus a change needs to be made in PointCounter, specifically: PointCounter.AddPoint('Blue').

What is an efficient and elegant way of achieving this (and many similar interactions)?

I can think of two ways, both with downsides:

a) Every method call passes back whatever consequences from the call need to happen elsewhere in the game. This would then get passed up the chain and (potentially) get passed down again to other contained objects. So when blue places a Pawn in SpaceOne, "Add a point for blue" gets passed up to AreaOne, Board, Game and then down to PointTracker. 
This would require quite a bit of overhead in figuring out exactly which object would need to do what with what is passed on, which would be quite a bit of coding, error prone and inefficent (due to all the checking that needs to be done).

b) Give every object an instance of every other object it needs to make changes to. So SpaceOne would contain an instance of PointTracker and can directly call PointTracker.GivePoint('Blue') 
This is relatively easy in implementation and seems efficient in execution, but it would mean passing many different objects from all over the game to each other, which feels like it beats the purpose of object oriented programming.

Are there better methods?

And if not, is there a reason to prefer either a) or b)?

Comment: Hi, did you consider the listener/subscription pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to store the link back to the up level object in the next level object, that is:

- the `Board` object will have the link to related `Game` object as an attribute,
- the `AreaOne` object will have the link to related `Board` object,
- the `SpaceOne` to the `AreaOne`.

Thus, you can reach the needed `Game` object from the `SpaceOne` by this way:

```
# Get the `SpaceOne` object
space_one = game.board.area_one.space_one

# Climb to the `Game` object from the `SpaceOne` object,
# then go to the `point_tracker`
# and call its `AddPoint(player1)` method.
space_one.area_one.board.game.point_tracker.AddPoint(player1)
```

#### Uml diagram:

[image]

#### My implementation:

```
# Auxiliary class - for a class name printing
class Base(object):
    def print_class_name(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class Game(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.point_tracker = None
        self.board = None

class PointTracker(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = 1

    def AddPoint(self, player):
        player.counter += self.points
        print(f"The {player.name}'s points: = {player.counter}")

class Board(Base):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.area_one = None

class AreaOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.space_one = None

class SpaceOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, area_one):
        self.area_one = area_one

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.name = color
        self.counter = 0

def create_game():
    game = Game()

    game.point_tracker = PointTracker()
    game.board = Board(game)

    game.board.area_one = AreaOne(game.board)

    game.board.area_one.space_one = SpaceOne(game.board.area_one)

    return game

### Testing
game = create_game()
player1 = Player('Blue')
player2 = Player('Green')

space_one = game.board.area_one.space_one

needed_point_tracker = space_one.area_one.board.game.point_tracker

needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player1)
needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player1)

needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player2)
needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player2)

needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player1)
needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player1)

needed_point_tracker.AddPoint(player2)
```

**Output**

```
The Blue's points: = 1
The Blue's points: = 2
The Green's points: = 1
The Green's points: = 2
The Blue's points: = 3
The Blue's points: = 4
The Green's points: = 3
```